# React Browser Router handling F5 - returning 404

Tags: reactjs

I have switched to BrowserRouter from HashRouter and all navigation works well - except F5.

I understand WHY it's failing.... Sending a request to www.example.com/account will result in a 404 as there is no such path on the server.

From what I have read, I need to add a catch-all. Bit not sure that is the fix. As the request hits the server before it hits my javascript SPA.

My routing is like this:

```
<Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route exact path="/accounts" component={Accounts} />
                <Route exact path="/accounts/:id" component={Accounts} />
                <Route exact path="/account" component={AccountEditor} />
```

But I feel I need to modify something lower down. I'm not sure if it's a server setting, because refeshing www.example.com/accounts/ will force a GET on the server and fail, before it even looks at my code.

I thought maybe webpack is the issue. But as I created my app with create-react-app, I can't find a webpack file. I'm not sure where that was all configured by create-react-app.

How can I handle a F5, or navigating direct to a url that isn't / ?
The host runs IIS, so I'm wondering if there is a web.config rule or something I can use to allow paths in the URL - but always GET from / ?

Comment: Are you running the application in `dev` or serving from the `build`?

Comment: In dev - it's OK. When I build and upload to server, I get the 404s.

Comment: it seems your request directly go to server instead of client. if you are using nginx/apache you can handle your routes to client first

Answer (score 0):

`React` build includes static files which includes chunk of `.js` files and a single `index.html` file. When you are uploading it to a traditional `ngnix` server it looks for the file as in the route. To override that and make this work you need to serve you static file using a static file server for `.js` application. What i mostly use is a `npm` package named as `serve`. You can install it on your server after installing `node.js` on it using:

```
npm i -g serve
```

And then you can use the following command to serve your application:

```
serve folder_name
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This might be right. I FTP my 'build' folder after running 'npm run-script build'. So I have no control of their server - I believe.

Comment: Would this be valid for a host running IIS?